# processing a dictionary in multithreading is locked

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to process a dictionary in a multiprocess scenario, but the process is locked and function process_data is never fired.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager = Manager()
    directoary_names = manager.dict(lock=True)
    time_list = manager.list()
    with lock:
        ts = datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-08-21', '%Y-%m-%d')
        end_ts = datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-8-21', '%Y-%m-%d')
        while ts <= end_ts:
            print(ts)
            ts += datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
            path = os.path.join(
                r'C:\\ahmed\\SpeedFT-meter1\\peakdata\\' + ts.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + r'\\peakdata_' + ts.strftime(
                    "%Y%m%d_%H%M") + r'.bz2')
            time_list.append(ts)
            directoary_names[path] = time_list.pop()

    modified_dic = directoary_names
    p = Pool(4)
    t = p.map(process_data, modified_dic)
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Comment: where is the `process_data` function?

Comment: @Netwave it just does this     print(directoary_names.values())

Comment: is it multiprocesing what you are using?

Comment: yes, using Pool

Comment: so, if you are using multiprocesing then the IO is not taking place in your current process. try to make `process_data` to return the values instead of printing them

Comment: and how would I use the values of the dictionary ? is it ok to use it ? I just want to see if the values of the dictionary are correct

Comment: yes, you should be able to use them. But remember that the data is not shared between them unless you make it specifically so